# android webview can not load any url

Tags: android, url, android-webview

I meet a serious problems when load url with android WebView, in case a page can not load url and the page is blank, other pages which use WebView are not load out the page and i must exit my app to reboot it, so the WebView page can load url success. I do not know why this happens?

Can somebody tell me Why and How to solve this questions?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some code that you already tried.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this on Your activity in Mainfest set this**

```
 android:onHistory="true"
```

**if You have problem also when not result than try this code also**

> On Create

```
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);




 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click..."+url);
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);


            //webview.reload();
        }


        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {



        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl("your Url");
```

> **Inside the class**

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }


 }

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Display confirmation here, finish() activity.
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

Comment: Dear Arjun saini, thank you for answer my question, but your code does not help me to solve my problems, my code is similar to you but the error is still exist, I am so puzzled...

Comment: have you put  android:onHistory="true" in AndroidMainfiest to your activity

Comment: I add this line but software give me tips it is unknown attribute, why? What mean this line?

Comment: You give permission//?? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: try to add this and try again <activity android:name=".YouActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

Comment: I had add the permission but no use!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may work

WebViewSampleActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebViewSampleActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webview;
private static final String TAG = "Main";
private ProgressDialog progressBar;  

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewSampleActivity.this, "WebView Example", "Loading...");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
            Toast.makeText(WebViewSampleActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(description);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add the internet permission in the manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Oh no，your answer does not solve my problems. My code are same to you and the problem that I meet still happened sometimes, but thank you all the way.